# I am facing difficulty to understand this program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=10;
    if(i==20 || 30)
    printf("True");
    else
    printf("False");
    return 0;
}
```

//Gives output:True
//Please tell me how this if loop is getting evaluated

Comment: It's not a loop, it's an execute-once statement called an if statement.  The expression `i == 20 || 30` will always be true.  It compares `i` to `20`, which in this case is false, then it compares `30` to zero.  Since `30` is non-zero, it is logically true, so the `if` expression is true (in fact, its value is `30`).  And it prints `True`.

Comment: I sense a voting ring here.

Comment: I sense a person posting the same question over and over.

Answer (score 4):

There is no loop here..

Just one condition check, which has the following condition.

```
if(i==20 || 30)
```

First, you should know, any non-zero value is taken as `True` in a condition check.

So, first `i` is checked with the value `20`, if thats true then `True` is printed, else it checks the next condition as there is an `OR` inbetween. SInce the next condition is non-zero which is always true, therefore it goes inside and prints `True`.

---

**NOTE:** This program will always print `True`, as the next condition is always true, and there is an `OR` in between which needs only one of the conditions to be true.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you want to check "if i is 20 or 30". The syntax for that is "if ( i is 20 ) or (i is 30)". The translation of that logic into code is:

```
if ( i == 20 || i == 30 )
```

When you use

```
if ( i == 20 || 30 )
```

it is translated as:

```
if ( (i == 20) || 30 )
```

regardless of what `(i == 20)` evaluates to, the conditional expression will always evaluate to "true" since `30` is a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement as two conditions
First is (i==20) and second is 30
The second conditions is 30 which is always true.
For "OR" operation any one true is enough to execute the if statements
So the statements under if are executecd

Answer (score 0):

**In your code:**

`i==20` give result `false` because `i=10`

`i==20 || 30` equals to `false || 30` give results `true` because 30 (or non-zero values) equal to `true` in condition check.

**It should be:**

```
if((i==20) || (i==30))
```

Comment: if in the program it was if(i==10 || 0) its again prints true

Comment: if in the program it was if(i==20 || 0)  it prints false

Answer (score 0):

The expression `if(i==20 || 30)` is turning out to be true(non zero) hence you are seeing the output as true. The expression will be evaluated according to the precedence at which the operators get evaluated. `==` has higher precedence than  `||` hence `i==20` will be evaluated first and the result becomes as follows

```
if( true || 30 )
```

Now the operator is `||` the Left operand will be checked first which is true and control enters if block and prints true. This is called short circuit evaluation. If we have logical `||` operator, first the Left operand will be evaluated. If the left operand is true compiler wont evaluate right operand.